# local.ERROR: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation

Tags: php

estoy realizando un proyecto en Laravel 7 en el cual estoy intentando cargar imágenes al servidor mediante la librería **Dropzone Js** pero al momento de hacer las pruebas de subir la imagen me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se me hace raro ya que en mis archivos **JS** y **PHP** no me muestra ningún error de sintaxis o algo así.
Imágenes del código **JS y PHP**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Cómo podría solucionar este problema?**

*Cabe mencionar que para la manipulación de las imágenes también estoy usando la librería **Intervention Image***

Actualización: He revisado el archivo log de laravel y veo el siguiente error:

```
[2020-10-17 20:43:36] local.ERROR: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation. {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Intervention\\Image\\Exception\\NotSupportedException(code: 0): GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation. at C:\\Users\\ivan21\\Documents\\Curso Laravel\\Establecimientos\\Establecimientos\\vendor\\intervention\\image\\src\\Intervention\\Image\\Gd\\Driver.php:19)
```

Comment: Dirígete a tu log de errores en laravel y verifica el mensaje de error asociado al status 500, una vez hecho eso pégalo en tu pregunta

Comment: intenta instalando la libreria que te pide `sudo apt-get install php7.1-gd`

Answer (score 2):

Después de las sugerencias que me brindaron algunos miembros de ésta comunidad y de investigar un poco más de información en internet encontré la solución y lo que hice fue descomentar la linea en el archivo **php.ini** que muestro a continuación:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo la linea originalmente se encuentra así `;extension=gd2` y lo que hice fue quitar el punto y coma del inicio.

Ahora en lugar del error me devuelve la respuesta del servidor que imprimo en la consola del navegador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]