# GD Library Extension - no esta disponible para esta instalación de PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel 6 y quise hacer uso de la libreria Intervention para mostrar un preview de imágenes y a la hora de guardar la imagen en la base de datos, muestra el error:

`GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation`

Y sin embargo si almacena la información en la base de datos y también me genera el thumbnail de mi imagen.

Utilizo: Xampp, PHP8, Apache 2.4

Estuve buscando soluciones en otras preguntas relacionadas y he intentado:

- `Des-comentar la linea gd` en mi archivo php.ini y no funciona.
- He realizado la instalación de la librería nuevamente a través de `composer require intervention/image` siguiendo la [Documentación de Intervention](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)
- He realizado la prueba con una versión anterior de php, ejemplo PHP7.3.2 y funciona bien.

Siguiendo este error a través de github [Issue/#1061](https://github.com/Intervention/image/issues/1061) se menciona que es un error de compatibilidad entre la librería y la version de PHP.

Alguien sabe mas respecto a este problema? Agradecería cualquier comentario.

Comment: ¿intentaste con instalar php-gd? ¿Estás seguro que está disponible como librería para tu sistema? Yo uso Linux y con hacer `sudo apt install php-gd` y `sudo service apache2 restart` funcionó.

Comment: Gracias por comentar, para tu primer pregunta lo respondo en mi pregunta, para asegurarme de lo demás he limpiado el cache de mi app usando `cache:clear , config:clear , config:cache` y por si fuera poco hice un `dump-autoload` a mi proyecto y `también reinicie mi servidor` ; Saludos.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [local.ERROR: GD Library extension not available with this PHP installation](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/399068/local-error-gd-library-extension-not-available-with-this-php-installation)